# does local git repo get initialize with the same files

Tags: git

I'm on a mac and installed git locally. My question is If i have a web project created at say

```
/Volumes/www/myproject
```

And I want to initialize my current project into git Do I initialize it in the same folder myproject or it can be at another location that i choose?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it as you wish. If you do it in the same folder, it creates a `.git` folder inside it.

Comment: you mean it's not important where you put it?

Answer (score 0):

If you change the location, i guess you need to copy the .git directory too and do a

git commit -a

and uncomment the changes that you have made